Call different constructor in template depending on available constructor
I have something like this:
#include <type_traits>

class Base {
};

class A : Base {
  public:
    A(int x) {}
};

class B : Base {
  public:
    B(int x, float y) {}
};

template<typename T>
T * f(int x, float y) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value);
    if constexpr ( /* T(int) exists */ ) {
        return new T(x);
    } else {
        return new T(x, y);
    }
}

int main() {
    f<A>(5, 2.5);
    f<B>(5, 2.5);
}

Using C++23. Basically I have different subclasses that have different arguments for their constructor, and I have a template function that can take any of the subclasses, and I need it to call the constructor (with different arguments depending on the subtype).
I have like over a dozen classes with 2 constructor signatures ((int) and (int, float) in this example), so anything that involves hardcoding A and B cases for the body of f is no good. There's also an existing inheritance hierarchy, so I can't easily create an intermediate class providing a virtual constructor or something, unless there's a solution with multiple inheritance. Avoiding a vtable would also be good because of space overhead.
My current attempt is this (using CRTP to get a static field with different values for each class):
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Derived>
class Base {
  public:
    static constexpr bool CONSTRUCTOR_TAKES_FLOAT = false;
};

class A : Base<A> {
  public:
    static constexpr bool CONSTRUCTOR_TAKES_FLOAT = false;
    A(int x) {}
};

class B : Base<B> {
  public:
    static constexpr bool CONSTRUCTOR_TAKES_FLOAT = true;
    B(int x, float y) {}
};

template<typename T>
T * f(int x, float y) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base<T>, T>::value);
    if constexpr (T::CONSTRUCTOR_TAKES_FLOAT) {
        return new T(x);
    } else {
        return new T(x, y);
    }
}

int main() {
    f<A>(5, 2.5);
    f<B>(5, 2.5);
}

This does not compile though; it seems if constexpr is not enough to prevent the compiler from trying to resolve the wrong constructor call. I have also tried using boost::hana::eval_if, but that only prevents evaluation of one branch, whereas I would need to prevent evaluation of both branches since both constructor calls are invalid for the other case.
How do I do this? A clean solution without the boolean flag in each class would be nice, but the flags are fine too.

Edit: I thought I had a minimum working example because it failed to compile and the error message was about the signatures, but as pointed out in a comment, that error was because I just got the two branches backwards. If that is fixed, the above code compiles.
However my real code still did not compile and it did not have the branches backwards. I identified what was making my code fail was that the boolean flag in the derived class was private, not public. The base class did have it as public though, so the access to the boolean flag of the derived class from a function outside the class just got the value in the base class, causing the if constexpr to go to the wrong branch.
The answers here have still been valuable though, as std::is_constructible is a cleaner solution than the boolean flags, which is what I wanted.
As a side-note it seems that std::constructible_from is a concept, which I guess can also be used in conditionals even though the use case for concepts (if I understand correctly) is restricting type parameters? And also it seems the std::constructible_from requires not only std::is_constructible but also std::descructible, though I'm not sure how exactly a type would not be destructible (maybe deleting the destructor?).
Anyway thank you for your answers

"This does not compile though" Because you got the order wrong, it should be if constexpr (!T::CONSTRUCTOR_TAKES_FLOAT).

btw in the title you say "depending on subclass" but then you explain that switching on the subclass is not an option and that you merely want to check which constructor is present

@康桓瑋 You are right, thank you. See my update to the question

@463035818_is_not_an_ai You're right, I've updated the title

You can use the std::constructible_from concept:
template<typename T>
T * f(int x, float y) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value);
    if constexpr (std::constructible_from<T,int> ) {
        return new T(x);
    } else {
        return new T(x, y);
    }
}

Live Demo
Perhaps you'll need to swap the branches to handle cases when subclasses with (int,float) constructor have a default argument for the float.

As mentioned in a comment, your approach with the static bool fails to compile because you have a typo in the condition. It should be if constexpr (!T::CONSTRUCTOR_TAKES_FLOAT) {. See https://godbolt.org/z/jh9YhK4rr.


I have also tried using boost::hana::eval_if, but that only prevents evaluation of one branch [...]

That should work too. In every instantiation of the template only one of the branches needs to be discarded.

Thanks. Regarding the hana::eval_if solution though, it is specifically the else branch that does not get evaluated if the condition is true, while the if branch is always evaluated. At least if I understand correctly. So that is still an issue. constructible_from works though and is a better solution

The constexpr if should work, if not there is something else wrong with the code. Maybe the duplicate flag in the base class causes the issue.
Either way, you don't need the flags. Use std::is_constructible with constexpr if to work out which constructor is usable. This does not require crtp or flags.

I didnt know about either solution and now I am a bit confused about the inconsistent naming between is_constructible and constructible_from when they appear to do the same

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Since most of concepts of the standard library comes from an already existing type traits, they need a different name (e.g. std::is_integral and std::integral). Here they did the same, i.e. std::is_constructible is the "old" type trait and std::constructible_from is the corresponding concept.

@Fareanor ok I can buy that, but why is it not called std::constructible ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I assume because when you're using the concept to constrain a template arg, for example template<std::constructible_from<int> MyType> MyType make_my_type(int), then it reads a lot nicer with the _from than without.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Indeed the naming is inconsistent. Whether or not it should have the _from suffix, it should be the same for both the type trait and the concept.
